# itext pdf fields are not filled in the document orientation

Tags: java, android, pdf, itext

I create the PDF programmatically, setting the Document orientation like this:

```
public Document createStableFordPDF(Context ctx){
    Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4.rotate());
    try {
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document,
                new FileOutputStream(ctx.getExternalCacheDir().getAbsolutePath()+"/StableFord.pdf"));

        document.open();
...
```

The created document looks good :
[image]

And when I try to fill the empty fields , they appears in the wrong orientation

```
 public void fillStablefordPDF(Context ctx) {
    OutputStream output = null;
    try {
        output = new FileOutputStream(ctx.getExternalCacheDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/StableFord_filled.pdf");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(new FileInputStream(ctx.getExternalCacheDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/StableFord.pdf"));
        PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, output);
        AcroFields acroFields = stamper.getAcroFields();
       ...
       acroFields.setField("Name", "TOM");
```

See created document:
[image]

What should I do to fill those fields with the correct orientation?

Comment: You'll need to add rotation values to the fields: your filled pdf is output as expected for the construction arguments, I'll see if I can dig up an example

Comment: Alternatively simple replace `PageSize.A4.rotate()` by `new RectangleReadOnly(842,595)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I succeed by setting a roration to my fields as Samuel said
My PdfCellEvent class:
public class MyCellField implements PdfPCellEvent {

```
public MyCellField(String fieldname) {
    this.fieldname = fieldname;
    this.color = BaseColor.BLACK;
}

 @Override
public void cellLayout(PdfPCell cell, Rectangle rectangle, PdfContentByte[] canvases) {
    final PdfWriter writer = canvases[0].getPdfWriter();
    final TextField textField = new TextField(writer, rectangle, fieldname);
    textField.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
    textField.setTextColor(color);
    textField.setFontSize(10);
    textField.setRotationFromPage(PageSize.A4.rotate());
try {
        final PdfFormField field = textField.getTextField();
        writer.addAnnotation(field);
    } catch (final IOException ioe) {
        throw new ExceptionConverter(ioe);
    } catch (final DocumentException de) {
        throw new ExceptionConverter(de);
    }
}
```